# Shell script won't reading non- .sh files

Tags: shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p
do
  echo "$p"
done < numbers.txt
```

This script is only reading and allowing me to print .sh files. I have tried it with .txt files (like above but it does not print anything.)

Comment: Please add a sample of the contents of `numbers.txt`.  The filename suffix means nothing on Unix systems. Both `.sh` and `.txt` files are just text files.

Comment: I added a screen shot of both files

Comment: Is `numbers.txt` properly line-terminated? What happens if you change `while read p` to `while read p || [ -n "$p" ]`?

Comment: @steeldriver that worked! What exactly was the problem?

Comment: Please, [don't post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text).

Comment: Your file does not contain a single _terminated_ line.  `read` can only read complete lines.

Comment: I guess it would be more correct to say that `read` reads the line (and assigns it to variable `p`) but returns false, having encountered EOF while doing so: hence the body of the `while` loop is not executed.

Comment: @steeldriver That would be a more correct way of phrasing it, yes.  In fact, what I said was not correct.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are printing `test` not variable `p`
Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read p
do
  echo "$p"
done < numbers.txt
```

Test:

```
$ cat numbers.txt
1
2
345
678
9
$ bash script.sh
1
2
345
678
9
$
```

Comment: my apologies. I forgot to edit that ou, I was just testing something there. But even when changing to echo "$p", nothing prints

Comment: @CesaSalaam It works for me, are you sure that numbers.txt file is not empty?